# Mini processor's FSM stuck in branch equal loop

Tags: verilog, pipeline, system-verilog, processor, fsm

We're writing a mini processor that parses information according to instructions written to its' memory.

The first instruction (address 0 in memory) in our testbench is a **while loop** written as a branch equal: `if (delimeter == 0) jump 0`.

In order to differentiate between the case of waiting for delimeter and a general case of branch equal (or branch not equal), we added a specific waiting_for_delimeter signal but the instruction fetching takes a clock cycle and because the pipeline inserts a NOP (no operation instruction) for a taken branch, in the next clock waiting_for_delimeter cannot be 1 because it "sees" a NOP and not the branch equal instruction.

Can someone please help us to solve this?

Thanks!

[Simulation Waves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAiFs.jpg)

Comment: which language are you talking about?  Can you provide more code?

Comment: I'm writing in Verilog

Comment: [please see relevant code here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRDUn.png

Comment: there is no while loop in this code. there is no 'if'. there is no 'jump' instruction in verilog. Please formulate your question correctly with all supporting code samples, preferably **not** as images.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand from your question if the signal waiting_for_delimiter sees the branch, gets set to 1, and then reset to zero because of the NOP, or it's never get sets because it never sees the branch.

**For the first case:**

If you want to "remember" the signal waiting_for_delimiter should be 1 at the next cycle, just sample it using a FF:

```
reg waiting_for_delimiter_r1;

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) 
     if (rst)
        waiting_for_delimiter_r1 <= 1'b0;
     else
        waiting_for_delimiter_r1 <= waiting_for_delimiter;
```

This way, on the next cycle you will have the proper indication in waiting_for_delimiter_r1.

**For the second case:**

Follow the same approach, and sample the instruction or the indication that the branch was taken. Use this sampling in the waiting_for_delimiter logic.